# DS-160 Form info after submission

Tags: usa, student-visas

I have submitted my DS-160 form and taken an appointment date already. Now, when I went to the CEAC website again and retrieved the form by creating a new application, I see that the answers of some questions are missing. See the screenshot below. Also, social media info, email addresses are missing. Now, is it possible that I submitted the application without answering these questions?

[image]

1. Have you made specific travel plans?
2. Are you a permanent resident of a country/region other than your country/region of origin (nationality) indicated above?

I guess those questions were mandatory, so without answering them I certainly could not submit the application.

Now, is it normal that some info on DS-160 does not show when the submitted application is retrieved? Or, should I submit a new application and update the confirmation ID on CGI Federal website?